# Laravel5でのCookieの区別について

Tags: laravel-5

いつもお世話になっています。
Laravel5.3で開発を行っていますが、Cookie操作で躓いています。

クッキーのセットを

```
Cookie::queue(cookie('name', '名前', 60));
```

で行い、

```
$cookie = Request::cookie('name');
```

で取得している場合、
例えば、YamadaControllerで取得しても、TanakaControllerで取得しても、同じ値になりますよね。
例えばyamada.nameやtanaka.nameのように、使用するコントローラー別に区別を付けて保存することは出来ないのでしょうか？
大人しくyamada_name等にするべきですか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

クッキーに直接ネームスペースを反映されることはできないので、
質問のような使い方を想定する場合はプログラムの方で値を加工してあげる必要があります。

ネームスペース自体の取得は

PHPのマニュアルにある通り（http://php.net/manual/ja/language.namespaces.nsconstants.php）

```
__NAMESPACE__
```

となりますので、そのまま組合せて保存するか、laravelのネームスペース等が
App¥Http¥Controllers¥***;
などと冗長の場合は、文字列操作の処理で対応できるかと思います。

Comment: なるほど、勉強になりました。まだLaravel触り始めでネームスペース等々まで辿り着けていないので、そちらはじっくり勉強することにして、一旦そのままで出来ないことがわかって助かりました！出来ないことを試行錯誤していたので…。本当にありがとうございました！